# IE 9 innerHTML not working with select elements created by dataTables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, datatables, innerhtml

I'm working with http://www.datatables.net/. I've created select elements for each column that holds a distinct list of column values. When a select.change() is called I wrote code to recreate the selects(except the one clicked) based on the new table data. This works great in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 10. I can't figure out how to get it to work with IE 9, and I'm about ready to do some Hulk smash.

.innerHTML doesn't work. Jquery's .html() doesn't work. I've tried .addChild() instead of options.add(). Nothing works. The selects will either be empty, they won't get filtered, or after one is filtered none of the rest set off a select.change() event.

EDIT: I've also tried going back to the parentElement.innerHTML() on a recreate in order to grab the TH instead of the select as the first time the table is created th.innerHTML = select is used.

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
                /* Initialise the DataTable */
                var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
                    "sDom": '<"top"i>',
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bSort": false
                })
                /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
                $("thead th").each(function (i) {
                    this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(i), i);
                    $('select', this).change(function () {
                        oTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), i);

                        // Get array of select controls
                        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

                        // Loop through select controls
                        for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                            // If filtered array is not empty
                            if (filtered.length > 0) {
                                // If column currently being looped is not in filtered array
                                if ($.inArray(j, filtered) < 0) {
                                    // If column currently being looped is not the column clicked
                                    if ((this).textContent != a[j + 1].textContent) {
                                        a[j + 1].innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(j), j); // Recreate drop down list for currently looping column
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        filtered.push(j); // Add column to filtered array
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                    // If title is selected and currently looping column is the column selected
                                    if ($(this).val() == "" && j == i) {
                                        var index = $.inArray(j, filtered);  // Get index of column in filtered array
                                        filtered.splice(index, 1);           // Remove column from filtered array
                                        a[i + 1].innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(i), i); // Recreate drop down list for column selected (Because resetting drop down)
                                    }
                            }
                            else {
                                // If column currently being looped is not the column clicked
                                if ((this).textContent != a[j + 1].textContent) {
                                    // THE JQUERY WAY
                                    //var col;
                                    //switch (a[j + 1].id) {
                                    //    case "Dest": col = "#Dest"; break;
                                    //    case "Leg": col = "#Leg"; break;
                                    //    case "Start": col = "#Start"; break;
                                    //    case "End": col = "#End"; break;
                                    //    case "Day": col = "#Day"; break;
                                    //    case "Sort": col = "#Sort"; break;
                                    //    case "Services Days": col = "#Service Days"; break;
                                    //}
                                    //$(col).html(fnReCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(j), j));

                                    // THE JAVASCRIPT WAY
                                    a[j + 1].innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(j), j); // Recreate drop down list for currently looping column  
                                }
                                else {
                                    filtered.push(j); // Add column to filtered array
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //$("select").hide().show(); // Might help with IE problems
                    });
                });
```

The fnGetColumnData function (gets distinct array of column values)

```
         (function ($) {
                   $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetColumnData = function (oSettings, iColumn, bUnique, bFiltered, bIgnoreEmpty) {
                    // check that we have a column id
                    if (typeof iColumn == "undefined") return new Array();

                    // by default we only want unique data
                    if (typeof bUnique == "undefined") bUnique = true;

                    // by default we do want to only look at filtered data
                    if (typeof bFiltered == "undefined") bFiltered = true;

                    // by default we do not want to include empty values
                    if (typeof bIgnoreEmpty == "undefined") bIgnoreEmpty = true;

                    // list of rows which we're going to loop through
                    var aiRows;

                    // use only filtered rows
                    if (bFiltered == true) aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplay;
                        // use all rows
                    else aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster; // all row numbers

                    // set up data array   
                    var asResultData = new Array();

                    for (var i = 0, c = aiRows.length; i < c; i++) {
                        iRow = aiRows[i];
                        var aData = this.fnGetData(iRow);
                        var sValue = aData[iColumn];

                        //if (sValue == "&nbsp;") {
                        //    sValue = "_";
                        //}

                        // ignore empty values?
                        if (bIgnoreEmpty == true && sValue.length == 0) continue;

                            // ignore unique values?
                        else if (bUnique == true && jQuery.inArray(sValue, asResultData) > -1) continue;

                            // else push the value onto the result data array
                        else asResultData.push(sValue);
                    }
                    return asResultData.sort();
                }
            }(jQuery));
```

The createSelect() that works fine in new browsers, and the reCreateSelect() I've been using to try things.

```
function fnCreateSelect(aData, j) {
                switch (j) {
                    case 0: j = "Dest"; break;
                    case 1: j = "Leg"; break;
                    case 2: j = "Start"; break;
                    case 3: j = "End"; break;
                    case 4: j = "Day"; break;
                    case 5: j = "Sort"; break;
                    case 6: j = "Service Days"; break;
                }

                var r = '<select id="'+j+'"><option value="">' + j + '</option>', i, iLen = aData.length;

                for (i = 0 ; i < iLen ; i++) {
                    r += '<option value="' + aData[i] + '">' + aData[i] + '</option>';
                }

                return r + '</select>';
            }
            function fnReCreateSelect(aData, j) {
                switch (j) {
                    case 0: j = "Dest"; break;
                    case 1: j = "Leg"; break;
                    case 2: j = "Start"; break;
                    case 3: j = "End"; break;
                    case 4: j = "Day"; break;
                    case 5: j = "Sort"; break;
                    case 6: j = "Service Days"; break;
                }

                var s = document.getElementById(j);
                var op0 = document.createElement("option");
                op0.text = "";
                op0.value = j;
                s.options.add(op0);

                var iLen = aData.length;

                for (i = 0 ; i < iLen ; i++) {
                    var op = document.createElement("option");
                    op.text = aData[i]
                    op.value = aData[i];
                    s.options.add(op);
                }

                return s;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the code inside the change event block outside of the dom.ready. Then I reregister the change event each time the filters are repopulated.

```
function selectEvent(table, t, i) {
                table.fnFilter($(t).val(), i);

                // Get array of select controls
                var a = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

                // Loop through select controls
                for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                    // If filtered array is not empty
                    if (filtered.length > 0) {
                        // If column currently being looped is not in filtered array
                        if ($.inArray(j, filtered) < 0) {
                            // If column currently being looped is not the column clicked
                            if ((t).textContent != a[j + 1].textContent) {
                                a[j + 1].outerHTML = a[j + 1].outerHTML.replace(a[j + 1].innerHTML + '</select>', fnReCreateSelect(table.fnGetColumnData(j), j) + '</select>'); // Recreate drop down list for currently looping column
                            }
                            else {
                                filtered.push(j); // Add column to filtered array
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            // If title is selected and currently looping column is the column selected
                            if ($(t).val() == "" && j == i) {
                                var index = $.inArray(j, filtered);  // Get index of column in filtered array
                                filtered.splice(index, 1);           // Remove column from filtered array
                                a[i + 1].inner = a[i + 1].outerHTML.replace(a[i + 1].innerHTML + '</select>', fnReCreateSelect(table.fnGetColumnData(i), i) + '</select>'); // Recreate drop down list for column selected (Because resetting drop down)
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                        // If column currently being looped is not the column clicked
                        if ((t).textContent != a[j + 1].textContent) {
                            var temp = fnReCreateSelect(table.fnGetColumnData(j), j);
                            var temp2 = a[j + 1].innerHTML;

                            //a[j + 1].innerHTML = fnReCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(j), j);
                            a[j + 1].outerHTML = a[j + 1].outerHTML.replace(a[j + 1].innerHTML + '</select>', fnReCreateSelect(table.fnGetColumnData(j), j) + '</select>'); // Recreate drop down list for currently looping column  
                            var temp3 = 5;
                        }
                        else {
                            filtered.push(j); // Add column to filtered array
                        }
                    }
                }
                $('select').change(this, function () {
                    selectEvent(oTable, this, this.parentElement.cellIndex);
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `<div>` before appending.

Comment: The trick is to user outerHTML to completely replace the select in stead of appending a select to a select...but after I filter one column it breaks none of the other selects fire the select.change() event.

Comment: I've had a lot of issues with the change event in jQuery and IE.  I've had more success with bind.  

$('select').bind('change', function(){ /* do stuff */ });

If you can post a semi-working example somewhere this would probably be much easier to help with.  :)